# Import n svg file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, svg, import, android-jetpack-compose

I have tried to import svg files in Android Studio via

New  - Import Asset ...

but it seems there is no fully support for svg ... it converts the file to xml but the text disappears

e.g.

```
  ERROR @ line 27: <text> is not supported
ERROR @ line 27: <tspan> is not supported
```

Are there other ways to achieve the goal?

edit:
I have tried now ...

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Show_map(picName:String) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val svgString = loadSvgFromRaw(mContext, R.raw.nomap)
        val imageBitmap = convertSvgToImageBitmap(mContext,svgString!!)
        imageBitmap?.let {
            drawImage(
                image = it,
                topLeft = Offset.Zero,
                alpha = 1.0f
            )
        }
    }
}
fun loadSvgFromRaw(context: Context, resourceId: Int): String? {
    return try {
        val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(resourceId)
        val size = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer)
        inputStream.close()
        String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}

fun convertSvgToImageBitmap(context: Context,svgString: String): ImageBitmap {
    val svgString = loadSvgFromRaw(context, R.raw.nomap)
    val svg = SVG.getFromString(svgString)
    val targetWidth = 200 
    val targetHeight = 200 

    val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
        .override(targetWidth, targetHeight)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)

    val drawable = Glide.with(context)
        .`as`(Drawable::class.java)
        .load(svg)
        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
        .apply(requestOptions)
        .submit()
        .get()

    return (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap.asImageBitmap()
}
```

But got an error at get() on runtime - You must call this method on a background thread - before shows Android Studio no error

Any ideas? - app shows a white Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried several times - too much code for nothing

Changed to Coil

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.4.0")

@Composable
fun ImageExample() {
    AsyncImage(
        model = R.drawable.boing1,
        contentDescription = "This is an example image"
    )
```

And ... - its working very easy with svg files

another workaround is to export svg files in Adobe Illustrator
and setting dialog to convert text to outline

Answer (score 1):

Use AndroidSVG library: AndroidSVG is a library that allows you to directly render SVG images in Android. You can add the library to your project by including the following dependency in your app's build.gradle file:

`implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.4'`

Answer (score 0):

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Show_map(picName:String) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val svgString = loadSvgFromRaw(mContext, R.raw.nomap)

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val imageBitmap = convertSvgToImageBitmap(mContext,svgString!!)

          //   SVG.registerExternalFileResolver()

            imageBitmap?.let {
                drawImage(
                    image = it,
                    topLeft = Offset.Zero,
                    alpha = 1.0f
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
fun loadSvgFromRaw(context: Context, resourceId: Int): String? {
    return try {
        val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(resourceId)
        val size = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer)
        inputStream.close()
        String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}

suspend fun convertSvgToImageBitmap(context: Context,svgString: String): ImageBitmap {
    val svgString = loadSvgFromRaw(context, R.raw.nomap)
    val svg = SVG.getFromString(svgString)
    val targetWidth = 200
    val targetHeight = 200

    val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
        .override(targetWidth, targetHeight)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)

    val drawable = Glide.with(context)
        .`as`(Drawable::class.java)
        .load(svg)
        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
        .apply(requestOptions)
        .submit()
        .get()

    return (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap.asImageBitmap()
}
```

I have changed the code it does not work anyway get an error

Failed to find any ModelLoaders registered for model class: class com.caverock.androidsvg.SVG